# Cannot find reference 'services' in '__init__.py' Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

For some odd reason, Pycharm is not recognizing modules in my Django project.
I looked online and there are a bunch of solutions that I tried:

1. deleting .idea
2. invalidating cache and restarting
3. making the /beagle folder the source root

None of those work.

here is where I import the module:
*beagle/apps/memberships/models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from beagle.services import plaid_api, stripe_api
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting their user support?

Comment: no I have not. Was hoping to solve that issue myself.

Comment: Try Cmd+click on `beagle` in `from beagle.services import ...` where it brings you? Is the location expected? Perhaps IDE got confused by a runtime magic happening inside the `__init__.py`? Some hardcore `__all__` manipulations there? Feel free to drop a support request at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com or the issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY